# koa-router error router.routes is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router

When I try to use [koa-route](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router) 3.2.0 example from their website, I got error message `router.routes is not a function`

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const router = require('koa-route');

const app = new Koa();
app.use(logger());

router.get('/users', (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.response.body =`<h1>Hello!</h1>`;
});

app.use(router.routes())
   .use(router.allowedMethods());

// don't listen to this port if the app is required from a test script
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(1337);
  console.log('listening on port: 1337');
}
```

I got error message:

```
app.use(router.routes())
               ^

TypeError: router.routes is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Projects/shoucast-front-end-prototype/script/server.js:40:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

When I try to change

```
const router = require('koa-route');
```

to

```
var router = require('koa-router')();
```

I got error message:

```
const router = require('koa-route')();
                                   ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Projects/shoucast-front-end-prototype/script/server.js:2:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've installed the newer version, available at https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/tree/master

You need to use `new Router()` instead.

Also looks like you're mixing up `koa-router` with `koa-route`, which are two different packages.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

router.get('/', function (ctx, next) {
  // ctx.router available
});

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

Comment: and used `koa-route` instead of `koa-router` :/